# Reentrant Lock Problems

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm writing a program that creates a user input pane and needs to wait for the user to click "query" before it performs any calculations. Currently, I'm using a ReentrantLock to do this.

```
input = new InputPanel(config, files, runLock);
JScrollPane inputScroll = new JScrollPane(input);

cySouthPanel.add("MyProgram", inputScroll);
cySouthPanel.setSelectedIndex(cySouthPanel.indexOfComponent("MyProgram"));

runLock.lock();
    try {
         // do stuff
    }
    finally {
         runLock.unlock();
    }
```

I currently acquire the lock in the constructor of InputPanel and release it when the user clicks the 'query' button, but my program does not stop when it encounters `runLock.lock()` above. Any ideas as to why?

**EDIT:** My problem stems from the fact that the InputPanel runs in the same thread as the function that I have described above. In this case `lock()` does not block.

I need a way to wait for the program to wait for the InputPanel. Would creating my own threads be a viable alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit*
What it sounds like you will want to do is use a `CountDownLatch`.  You will create the latch with a value of 1 (`new CountDownLatch(1)`).  And then await.

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
input = new InputPanel(config, files, latch);
JScrollPane inputScroll = new JScrollPane(input);

cySouthPanel.add("MyProgram", inputScroll);
cySouthPanel.setSelectedIndex(cySouthPanel.indexOfComponent("MyProgram"));

latch.await();
```

Then, in your gui code, you will need to call `latch.countDown()` once the button is pressed.

Comment: This is already being done inside the InputPanel. However, I also need to do work outside the InputPanel.

Comment: @Alex, what do you mean by outside the input panel?

Comment: I'm writing a program with a 'main' method. When the user clicks the query button the input panel creates an input object and passes it back to the main method. I need to do other things with it in the main method, but need to wait for the object to be created.

Comment: @Alex, I see.  In that case, can you use a modal dialog to do this?  It will automatically block for user input.

Comment: No, it specifically needs to be a panel as it is a plug in to another program.

Comment: @Alex, I edited my answer.  You will probably want to use a CountDownLatch.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it is down to timing. You might find a CountDownLatch ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html ) a better fit for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by creating separate threads for each part of the program and exchanging the lock between them.